# Flink Table API -> Streaming Sink?

Tags: apache-flink

I see examples that convert a Flink `Table` object to a `DataStream` and run `StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute`.

how would I code + run a continuous query that writes to a Streaming Sink with the table API without converting to a DataStream.

It seems this must be possible, because otherwise what is the purpose of specifying streaming sink Table Connectors?

The Table API docs list continuous queries and dynamic tables, yet most of the actual Java APIs and code examples seem to only use the table API for batch.

**EDIT**: To show David Anderson what I'm trying, here are the three Flink SQL CREATE TABLE statements on top of analogous Derby SQL tables.

I see the JDBC table connector sink supports streaming, but am I not configuring this correctly? I don't see anything that I'm overlooking.
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/connectors/jdbc.html

FYI, when I get my toy example working, I am planning on using Kafka in production for input/output stream-like data and JDBC/SQL for the lookup table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE LookupTableFlink (
  `lookup_key` STRING NOT NULL,
  `lookup_value` STRING NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (lookup_key) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'jdbc',
  'url' = 'jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=false',
  'table-name' = 'LookupTable'
),

CREATE TABLE IncomingEventsFlink (
  `field_to_use_as_lookup_key` STRING NOT NULL,
  `extra_field` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `proctime` AS PROCTIME()
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'jdbc',
  'url' = 'jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=false',
  'table-name' = 'IncomingEvents'
), jdbcUrl);

CREATE TABLE TransformedEventsFlink (
  `field_to_use_as_lookup_key` STRING,
  `extra_field` INTEGER,
  `lookup_key` STRING,
  `lookup_value` STRING
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'jdbc',
  'url' = 'jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=false',
  'table-name' = 'TransformedEvents'
), jdbcUrl);
```

```java
String sqlQuery =
                "SELECT\n" +
                "  IncomingEventsFlink.field_to_use_as_lookup_key, IncomingEventsFlink.extra_field,\n" +
                "  LookupTableFlink.lookup_key, LookupTableFlink.lookup_value\n" +
                "FROM IncomingEventsFlink\n" +
                "LEFT JOIN LookupTableFlink FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF IncomingEventsFlink.proctime\n" +
                "ON (IncomingEventsFlink.field_to_use_as_lookup_key = LookupTableFlink.lookup_key)\n";

Table joinQuery = tableEnv.sqlQuery(sqlQuery);
// This seems to run, return, and complete and doesn't seem to run in continuous/streaming mode.
TableResult tableResult = joinQuery.executeInsert(TransformedEventsFlink);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to a dynamic table by using `executeInsert`, as in

```java
Table orders = tableEnv.from("Orders");
orders.executeInsert("OutOrders");
```

The documentation is [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/tableApi.html#insert).

Comment: i just tried a simple example exactly like that and it seems to run a batch job not a continuous streaming job. executeInsert returns and it seems new events are no longer processed.

Comment: What was the source? Can you share a complete example? Streaming inserts are supported; not sure why it didn't work in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I add simplified code in the question. A full single file simple Java app is here: https://pastebin.com/0FmdFUB1

Comment: You can't use a JDBC table as an unbounded streaming table source. You need something like kafka, or a debezium changelog stream. For experimentation, flink-faker is convenient. See https://github.com/ververica/flink-sql-cookbook for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

It's explained [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/streaming/dynamic_tables.html#table-to-stream-conversion).

code example can be found [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/common.html#convert-a-table-into-a-datastream):

```
// get StreamTableEnvironment. 
StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = ...; // see "Create a TableEnvironment" section

// Table with two fields (String name, Integer age)
Table table = ...

// convert the Table into an append DataStream of Row by specifying the class
DataStream<Row> dsRow = tableEnv.toAppendStream(table, Row.class);

// convert the Table into an append DataStream of Tuple2<String, Integer> 
//   via a TypeInformation
TupleTypeInfo<Tuple2<String, Integer>> tupleType = new TupleTypeInfo<>(
  Types.STRING(),
  Types.INT());
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> dsTuple = 
  tableEnv.toAppendStream(table, tupleType);

// convert the Table into a retract DataStream of Row.
//   A retract stream of type X is a DataStream<Tuple2<Boolean, X>>. 
//   The boolean field indicates the type of the change. 
//   True is INSERT, false is DELETE.
DataStream<Tuple2<Boolean, Row>> retractStream = 
  tableEnv.toRetractStream(table, Row.class);
```

Comment: your code is converting the table to a DataStream and then using the DataStream API. I was asking how you can use the Table API with dynamic tables + continuous queries + streaming sinks to do this.